# How does one perform a recasting to a different struct in standard C?

Tags: c, struct

I just read this passage from PEP-3123

> Standard C defines that an object must be accessed only through a
>   pointer of its type, and that all other accesses are undefined
>   behavior, with a few exceptions. In particular, the following
>   code has undefined behavior::
>
> ```
>   struct FooObject{
>     PyObject_HEAD
>     int data;
>   };
>
>   PyObject *foo(struct FooObject*f){
>    return (PyObject*)f;
>   }
>
>   int bar(){
>    struct FooObject *f = malloc(sizeof(struct FooObject));
>    struct PyObject *o = foo(f);
>    f->ob_refcnt = 0;
>    o->ob_refcnt = 1;
>    return f->ob_refcnt;
>   }
> ```
>
> The problem here is that the storage is both accessed as
>   if it where struct `PyObject`, and as struct `FooObject`.
>
> Historically, compilers did not have any problems with this
>   code. However, modern compilers use that clause as an
>   optimization opportunity, finding that `f->ob_refcnt` and
>   `o->ob_refcnt` cannot possibly refer to the same memory, and
>   that therefore the function should return 0, without having
>   to fetch the value of ob_refcnt at all in the return
>   statement.

My C is very old-school and very rusty, and having done the above operation countless times I started wondering: in modern C, given a struct A, if I want to access its memory layout with the struct layout of an unrelated struct B, how does one do it? From the above statement it seems this is undefined behavior now.

Comment: This is UB no matter how you do it but using a union might avoid the unwanted optimization.

Answer (score 3):

> in modern C, given a struct A, if I want to access its memory layout
>   with the struct layout of an unrelated struct B, how does one do it?

One *does not* do it in a conforming program.

> From the above statement it seems this is undefined behavior now.

Such an operation has undefined behavior in *every* version of standard C.  That has not changed.  What has changed is the liberties that some compilers may choose to take in view of the undefinedness of the behavior.  The best alternative is to structure your code so that you don't exercise such behavior in the first place.

Supposing that your code exhibits such undefined behavior and you don't want to change it, you could consider declaring a union type containing members of both structure types involved:

```
union dummy {
    struct FooObject foo;
    struct PyObject  p;
};
```

Within the scope of such a union, the compiler the compiler *probably* will consider it unsafe to assume that pointers to those types do not alias each other.

If you are concerned only about a specific compiler, then it is possible that you can rely on a command-line option instead.  With GCC, for example, the `-fno-strict-aliasing` flag will globally disable optimizations that depend on assumptions that pointers to different types do not alias each other.

But I emphasize that both of those alternatives are workarounds, not *bona fide* solutions.

---

**Addendum:**

Do note, however, that if the first member declared by macro `PyObject_HEAD` has type `struct PyObject`,  then your `FooObject` / `PyObject` does not fit the pattern you asked about: type `struct FooObject` and `struct PyObject` are then *closely* related, by virtue of `FooObject` having a `PyObject` as its first member.

If that is the case then the standard guarantees that if `fp` is a pointer to a `FooObject`, then `(PyObject *) fp` is a valid pointer to the `PyObject` that is its first member.  Accessing the first member of a struct via a pointer to its type obtained in the way described has perfectly well-defined behavior.  Moreover, if the definition of type `struct FooObject` is in scope, and it declares a `struct PyObject` as its first member, then that serves better and more reliably than a union such as I described above.

None of that applies to the case of structures whose leading members merely have the same types, in the same order, however, which *used* to be the case produced by using `PyObject_HEAD`.  The whole point of PEP-3123 was to change from that case to the case where `PyObject_HEAD` declares (only) a `PyObject` itself, as just discussed, not the individual members of one.

Comment: The first element in an array is always represented in the same way as it would be outside of a struct. I don't know if the rule is the same for the rest of the members in certain C standards, but you can use a pointer cast to cast a struct to it's first element.

Comment: Yes, @YoYoYonnY, one can cast a struct pointer to a pointer to the type of the struct's first member, and access that member through the converted pointer.  But the OP asked about a different situation, where the pointed-to types are *unrelated*.  That latter was in fact the case produced by using `PyObject_HEAD` prior to the changes introduced by PEP-3123, and the whole point of that PEP was to change to the case you describe.  I have added an addendum to this answer to discuss those details.

Comment: Ok, but does this mean that if I want to create a struct containing 12 chars and a struct of three 32 bit floats, I can't cast one into the other?

Comment: @StefanoBorini, you cannot cast from any structure type to any other.  No such conversions are defined at all.  You can cast *a pointer to* one structure such as you describe to a pointer to the other structure type, but accessing the pointed-to object via the converted pointer produces UB, period.  In practice, the language provides no reason even in theory to expect to be able to rely on that, because the compiler is at liberty to insert padding into structure layouts between members and after the last member, at its own discretion.